# Counting Sick days over the weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server, weekend

I'm trying to solve a problem in the following (simplified) **dataset**:

| Name | Date | Workday | Calenderday | Leave |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PersonA | 2023-01-01 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonA | 2023-01-07 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonA | 2023-01-08 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonA | 2023-01-13 | 1 | 1 | Sick |
| PersonA | 2023-01-14 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonA | 2023-01-15 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonA | 2023-01-16 | 1 | 1 | Sick |
| PersonA | 2023-01-20 | 1 | 1 | Holiday |
| PersonA | 2023-01-21 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonA | 2023-01-22 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonA | 2023-01-23 | 1 | 1 | Holiday |
| PersonB | 2023-01-01 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| PersonB | 2023-01-02 | 1 | 1 | Sick |
| PersonB | 2023-01-03 | 1 | 1 | Sick |

Where the lines with NULL in [Leave] is weekend.

**What I want is a result looking like this:**

| Name | Leave | PeriodStartDate | PeriodEndDate | Workdays | Weekdays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PersonA | Sick | 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-16 | 2 | 4 |
| PersonA | Holiday | 2023-01-20 | 2023-01-23 | 2 | 4 |
| PersonB | Sick | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-03 | 2 | 2 |

where the difference between [Workdays] and [Weekdays] is that weekdays also counts the weekend.

What I have been trying is to first make a row (in two different ways)

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY \[Name\] ORDER BY \[Date\]) as RowNo1
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY \[Name\], \[Leave\] ORDER BY \[Date\]) as RowNo2
```

and after that to make a period base date:

```
DATEADD(DAY, 0 - \[RowNo1\], Date) as PeriodBaseDate1
,DATEADD(DAY, 0 - \[RowNo2\], \[Date\]) as PeriodBaseDate2
```

and after that do something like this:

```
MIN(\[Date\]) as PeriodStartDate
,MAX(\[Dato\]) as PeriodEndDate
,SUM(\[Calenderday\]) as Weekdays
,SUM(\[Workday\]) as Workdays
GROUP BY \[PeriodBaseDate (1 or 2?)\], \[Leave\], \[Name\]
```

But whatever I do I can't seem to get it to count the weekends in the periods.

It doesn't have to include my try with the RowNo, PeriodBaseDate etc.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products have their own set of functions. (E.g. DATEADD.)

Comment: I'm not totally sure if I ansver your question or make a fool out of myself for my lack of knowledge, but I work in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Then it's SQL Server. (There are dozens of other "SQL databases".)

Comment: Well, it could be Azure SQL Edge, Azure SQL Database, or Azure Synapse, I suppose, @jarlh . SSMS isn't limited to SQL Server any more.

Comment: @Larnu, I see. Same SQL version?

Comment: Syntax in Synapse can be very different, @jarlh . Azure SQL Edge is more like an even more stripped back version of Express (and can run on ARM), and Azure SQL Database can be seen as contained cloud hosted databases; so have many of the features of a full instance provided you are working inside a single database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't have your actual full solutions, I've provided a full working one. I firstly use `LAST_VALUE` to have all the rows have a value for their `Leave` (provided there was a non-`NULL` value previously).

Once I do that, you have a gaps and island problem, and can aggregate based on that.

I assume you are using SQL Server 2022, the latest version of SQL Server at the time of writing, as no version details are given and thus have access to the `IGNORE NULLS` syntax.

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-01'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-07'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-08'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-13'),1,1,'Sick'),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-14'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-15'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-16'),1,1,'Sick'),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-20'),1,1,'Holiday'),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-21'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-22'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonA',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-23'),1,1,'Holiday'),
            ('PersonB',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-01'),0,1,NULL),
            ('PersonB',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-02'),1,1,'Sick'),
            ('PersonB',CONVERT(date,'2023-01-03'),1,1,'Sick'))V(Name,Date,Workday,Calenderday,Leave);
GO
WITH Leaves AS(
    SELECT Name,
           [Date],
           Workday,
           Calenderday, --It's spelt Calendar, you should correct this typopgraphical error as objects with typoes lead to further problems.
           --Leave,
           LAST_VALUE(Leave) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date
                                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Leave
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT),
LeaveGroups AS(
    SELECT Name,
           [Date],
           Workday,
           CalenderDay,
           Leave,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Leave ORDER BY Date) AS Grp
    FROM Leaves)
SELECT Name,
       Leave,
       MIN([Date]) AS PeriodStartDate,
       MAX([Date]) AS PeriodEndDate,
       SUM(WorkDay) AS WorkDays, --Assumes Workday is not a bit, if it is, CAST or CONVERT it to a int
       DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN([Date]), MAX([Date]))+1 AS Weekdays
       --SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[Date])  + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN 1 END) AS Weekdays --This method is language agnostic
FROM LeaveGroups
WHERE Leave IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Name,
         Leave,
         Grp
ORDER BY Name,
         PeriodStartDate;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. Based on what I understood, below script gives the expected output.

```
SELECT Name, Leave, Min(Date) PeriodStartDate,Max(Date) PeriodEndDate, SUM(Workday) Workdays, DATEDIFF(DAY,Min(Date),Max(Date))+ 1  Weekdays from YourTable
WHERE Leave IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Name, Leave
```

Comment: I have tried your solution on the test-dataset I have listed in the table and I see I get the desired results. I will now try to see if I can fit it into the full dataset. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn’t work when more dates are added. 
Let’s say Person A has a sick day again on the date 2023-01-24 then the amount of weekdays it provides will be between first and last sick day (from 2023-01-13 to 2023-01-24)